# creating multiple instance in mysql 5.7 in windows 7

Tags: mysql, database

i go through MySQL documentation [Running Multiple MySQL Instances on Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-windows-servers.html) using windows,after that i created two my.cnf files and executed shows below error now

> mysqld: Can't change dir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

my my.cnf file for new instance are

```
[client]
port=3308
user=root
password=root

[mysqld]
datadir = H:/MySQL Datafiles
port = 3308
```

please give full steps to create an instance on MySQL along with with default instance which contain port=3306 what am i doing wrong i cant access it using sqlyog
it is running perfectely and default port is accesable

Answer (score 1):

I have several MySQL 5.5 instances running on different ports on my Windows 10. I think you need to specify both 'basedir' and 'datadir' path in your my.cnf file. I've done following changes in order to successfully run a new instance on my pc.

1. For second mysql instance, created a directory ‘Mysql2’ in my C: drive and copied following folders from ‘MySQL5.5’ to ‘Mysql2’ folder.

   •    bin
   •    data
   •    include
   •    lib 
   •    share
2. Copied my.ini from ‘MySQL5.5’ to ‘Mysql2’ folder and renamed as 'mysql2.ini’. Opened ‘mysql2.ini’ in Notepad editor and added following lines under [mysql] section.

   `basedir="C:/Mysql2/"
   datadir="C:/Mysql2/data/"`
3. In windows command-line editor executed following line to start new
   mysql instance as a service.
   `C:\Mysql2\bin>mysqld --installMysql2 --defaults-file=”C:/Mysql2/mysql2.ini”`
4. Started the new mysql instance with following command.

   `net start Mysql2`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help

```
# options for mysqld1 service
[mysqld1]
basedir = C:/mysql-5.1.55
port = 3307
enable-named-pipe
socket = mypipe1

# options for mysqld2 service
[mysqld2]
basedir = C:/mysql-5.5.54
port = 3308
enable-named-pipe
socket = mypipe2
```

Install the services as follows, using the full server path names to ensure that Windows registers the correct executable program for each service:

```
C:\> C:\mysql-5.1.55\bin\mysqld --install mysqld1
C:\> C:\mysql-5.5.54\bin\mysqld --install mysqld2
```

To start the services, use the services manager, or use NET START with the appropriate service names:

```
C:\> NET START mysqld1
C:\> NET START mysqld2
```

To stop the services, use the services manager, or use NET STOP with the appropriate service names:

```
C:\> NET STOP mysqld1
C:\> NET STOP mysqld2
```

Comment: service successfully installed but cant access that database which in port 3308(which mysqld installed)